# Remove objects with common variables in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a object array like this:

```
var objs = [
    {   x : 2,
        y : 2,
        a : true
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 2,
        a : false
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 3,
        a : false
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 4,
        a : false
    },
];
```

My objective is get only the objects that have the value of `a` set to `false`, so I did it:

```
var filter = objs.filter(function(obj) { return !obj.a; });
```

This works very well, but now I need remove each object that have the same `x` and `y` of other object and have the `a` set to `false` from the original array. So in my example, only the second object should be removed (`objs[1]`), because the `x` and `y` values are the same of `objs[0]`, but the `a` is set to `false`. The ouput of the example will be this:

```
var objs = [
    {   x : 2,
        y : 2,
        a : true
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 3,
        a : false
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 4,
        a : false
    },
];
```

A picture to be more clear:

[image: Example]

*Obs.: Vanilla JS only.*

Comment: Use `$.map()` jQuery method

Comment: The answer seems so straightforward — almost a direct translation of the words you used. Have you tried solving it yourself, and what thoughts have you had?

Comment: Do you mean to remove object `b` if `b.x === a.x && b.y === a.y` or to remove `b` if `b.x === b.y`?

Comment: You are correct @200_success, I edited the question to be more clearer.

Comment: @TeoMor the first one.

Comment: Your logic and requirements are unclear. Use accurate terms and notations ("*other object*" is cryptic), provide a wider example and *an exact* required output.

Comment: @Amit I tried make it more clear, see the edit.

Comment: That's still not clear (to me at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is always the tedious approach, which is to compare every element with every other element.  That's O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    if (!objs[i].a) continue;
    for (var j = objs.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if ( !objs[j].a &&
             objs[j].x == objs[i].x &&
             objs[j].y == objs[i].y ) {
            objs.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted an O(*n*) algorithm, then you could use a hash of some kind.

```
var discard = {};
objs.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj.a) discard[JSON.stringify([obj.x, obj.y])] = true;
});

objs = objs.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.a || !discard.hasOwnProperty(JSON.stringify([obj.x, obj.y]));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because you presented two ways to do it. I will use the O(n2) solution, its way faster than the other: https://jsperf.com/remove-duplicated-variables-in-array

Comment: For a small array like this, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to remove the elements with duplicate `x,y`
and of which `a` is set to false, otherwise, leave them in the array.
You may simply use `filter` to identify the duplicates this way.

```
var objs = [
    {   x : 2,
        y : 2,
        a : true
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 2,
        a : false
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 3,
        a : false
    },
    {   x : 2,
        y : 4,
        a : false
    },
];

function removeDup(objs){
    var uniq = objs.filter(function(n){
    var duplicates = objs.filter(function(m){
        return n.x==m.x && n.y==m.y
    });
    // If not duplicated, leave it
    // If duplicated and its `a` is false, remove it
    return (duplicates.length>1 && n.a) || (duplicates.length==1);
  })
  return uniq;
}

removeDup(objs); // [{"x":2,"y":2,"a":true},{"x":2,"y":3,"a":false},{"x":2,"y":4,"a":false}]
```